# difference between two strings and merge

Tags: php, string

Say I have string A: `/CI/index.php?/user/dashboard/`

And string B: `http://localhost/CI/index.php`

Using php how does one find the commonality between them aka `/CI/index.php` and remove it so that we are only left with `http://localhost/CI/index.php?/user/dashboard/`

Comment: Is the common part always the beginning of A and the end of B?

Comment: yes, but its not always the same

Answer (score 1):

The commented link from Mr Bahamondez didn't work for his specific problem.

Is this CodeIgniter? Wouldn't removing 'CI/index.php' with [htaccess rewrites](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=codeigniter%20urls&oq=codeigniter%20urls&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3606j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8&qscrl=1#q=remove%20CI/index.php&qscrl=1) be an easier option?

I've hacked this long winded essay of a lump of code together (it's late...) which I hope will help you - I'm sure someone else will do a better job, there's a problem though with getting the question mark back into the url.

```
$str1 = "http://localhost/CI/index.php";
$str2 = "/CI/index.php?/user/dashboard/";

// Take the url scheme and host out of the equation
$url_array = parse_url($str1 . $str2);

// store the path
$path = $url_array['path'];

// store the query (anything after a ?)
$query = $url_array['query'];

// Combine and split into an array using '/' as delimiter
$segments = explode("/", $path . $query);

// store the unique keys and filter out any empty values
$new_array = array_unique( array_filter($segments) );

var_export($new_array);
```

Result:

```
array (
  1 => 'CI',
  2 => 'index.php',
  5 => 'user',
  6 => 'dashboard',
)
```

Which you could then rebuild with

```
// Hacky rebuild the url
$segment = "";

foreach ($new_array as $seg) {
    $segment .= $seg . "/";
}

$new_url = $url_array['scheme'] . "://" . $url_array['host'] . "/" . $segment;
```

Which will give `http://localhost/CI/index.php/user/dashboard/`

**index.php** and **index.php?** causes a problem but if you have a specific case where you know that it will always be **/CI/index.php** maybe you can hack that out?

Comment: actually, the posted duplicate works fine for my method. but i really appreciate your work and will take it under advisement! upvoted